Azure Logic app task delete from queue sends 404 error "The response is not in a JSON format."
I have a logic app which takes as input a message from a queue. At the end of the workflow it should delete the message from the queue.
But in the delete task it gives back sometimes the 404 error "The response is not in a JSON format."
Thats how my task looks like and it works 90% of the runs, but in 10% it doesnt delete, the workflow runs again because it finds something in the queue and then the deletion works.

Does anybody have an idea why this happens and how it can be avoided?


Does anybody have an idea why this happens and how it can be avoided?

In order to avoid this, you can add the below steps in your workflow-

Add trigger  When there are messages in a queue (V2)  before Azure Queue delete message (V2) action to ensure that the workflow will trigger only when there is a message in the queue.



By doing so, your workflow will run in expected manner.



Or you can also use the Retry policy present in Delete message (v2) action.


